# Why am I not getting the actual source for the webpage?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webclient, webrequest

I'm currently playing around wtih the `HttpClient`, `WebRequest` and some other libraries. And I wanted to get the source for the microsoft store instagram page https://www.instagram.com/microsoftstore/

However when I tried getting it using `HttpClient` it's only getting the source for that white screen that shows up for a split second which looks like this [image]

This is the source I am getting
https://hatebin.com/lcujkzydfv

Why am I getting this and not the page that loads after that? The actual page with the content?

my code

```
 static string BASE_URL = "https://www.instagram.com/microsoftstore/";
        public static List<Profile> FindUser(string username)
        {
            //var web = new HtmlWeb();
            //var doc = web.Load(BASE_URL);


            string url = BASE_URL;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    // From String
                    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadHtml(result);

                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to `SPA` world where javascript renders rest of stuff. You might try out `Selenium` and get `PageSource`. Of course after some timeout

Answer (score 1):

This is how SPA (single page application) works.
The HTML is static and make call to server to get data and render it.
With webclient you get only the static html page and don't run the javascript code that run only in browser.

You have some ways to solve your problem:

1. Use instagram API instead of trying get data from website.
2. Use an automation over the browser you can control in your c# code. 
   Check `Selenium`.